# Search from the NSDATA

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I have following datav

```
   <050d00e7 f0e100aa ffffffff ffffff05 0d00e7f0 e100abff ffffffff ffff050d 00e7f0e1 00acffff ffffffff ff>
```

in NSDATA but i want to search for

```
      0d00e7f0 e100abff
```

so please help me how should I apply
[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) 
Please help

I used in this way

```
NSData *left1onData=[NSData dataWithBytes:left1on length:15];
NSRange left1onRange=[data rangeOfData:left1onData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[data length])];
```

**edit**
condition I use 
if(left1offRange.location==NSNotFound)

Answer (score 0):

Use below method:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfData:(NSData *)dataToFind options:(NSDataSearchOptions)mask range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

Comment: i used this method but it fails , i think i should set options?

Comment: What is the range that you have received in response?

Comment: it is undefined , its coming from server so that may send 10 packets to gether

Comment: No..No.. I am asking that the function which finds range of Data returns an object of NSRange. Can you tell me its value? If the returnedRange.length > 0 then it is having the data which you want to find.